# How can I initialize db ini on Ckan?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ckan, postgresql-9.6

I can't initialize my db on Ckan. I try to install Ckan 2.8 on ubuntu 16.04 and postgres 9.6 and I followed the instruction on the oficial [page](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html).

All is good but when I try to initialize my db, I can't.

This is the error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 102, in run
    invoke(command, command_name, options, args[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 141, in invoke
    exit_code = runner.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 236, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/cli.py", line 363, in command
    model.repo.init_db()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/model/__init__.py", line 188, in init_db
    self.upgrade_db()
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/model/__init__.py", line 266, in upgrade_db
    mig.upgrade(self.metadata.bind, self.migrate_repository, version=version)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 186, in upgrade
    return _migrate(url, repository, version, upgrade=True, err=err, **opts)
  File "<decorator-gen-16>", line 2, in _migrate
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 160, in with_engine
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 366, in _migrate
    schema.runchange(ver, change, changeset.step)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 93, in runchange
    change.run(self.engine, step)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/script/py.py", line 148, in run
    script_func(engine)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/migration/versions/016_uuids_everywhere.py", line 69, in upgrade
    drop_sequencies(migrate_engine)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/migration/versions/016_uuids_everywhere.py", line 186, in drop_sequencies
    migrate_engine.execute('drop sequence %s_id_seq;' % sequence)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2064, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 939, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1097, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) no existe la secuencia «package_extra_revision_id_seq»
 [SQL: 'drop sequence package_extra_revision_id_seq;']
```

I try to run:

- paster db init -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
- sudo ckan db init

I checked my db while the script was running and script created the sequence "package_extra_revision_id_seq" correctly. But when the script finishes the sequence "package_extra_revision_id_seq" no longer exists.

Comment: Can you please check the version of `psycopg2` if it is 2.7.3.2

Comment: Sure. I check it an this is the output: psycopg2==2.7.3.2

Comment: I've had an error similar to this in the past on a dev box. In my case(s) its normally that during install I copy and paste a command in the wrong order, skip one or grab an older version of something (e.g. run an install cmd for ubuntu 14 instead of 16).  If possible, try removing everything and installing from the start. It may not be this simple of a problem but worth a try.

I did notice though you're running the `paster` cmd to initialise but you've linked to install from package which says to use `sudo ckan db init`. Are you installing from source, package or docker?

Answer (score 1):

"CKAN 2.8 installing from source" paster db init is broken and not reported, so it won't work in anyway.  Solution is to install CKAN 2.7 instead as dependencies are different and working.

https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.7/

Once installed, paster command for init database works